# How do I list multiple dropdown menu's in alphabetical order - code tidy up

Tags: jquery

Currently I am using this code to list options in a dropdown menu list in alphabetical order. I am running this script multiple times per dropdown menu. I am just wondering if there is a way to do it for multiple menu's using the single script.

```
<script>
$(".field1").append($(".field1 option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));
</script>

<script>
$(".field2").append($(".field2 option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));
</script>

<script>
$(".field3").append($(".field3 option").remove().sort(function(a, b) {
var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
}));
</script>
```

Is there a way I can merge all of these three fields to sit inside a single  tag?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all of your fields in one selector, use .each to iterate over them, and use .children to select just that field's options for modification:

```
<script>
$(".field1, .field2, .field3").each(function(index, field){
 $(field).append($(field).children('option').remove().sort(function(a, b) {
    var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
  }));
});
</script>
```

e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/PmE2t/1466/

If all of your dropdowns share a common class it's even simpler:

```
<script>
$(".alphabetized-dropdown").each(function(index, field){
 $(field).append($(field).children('option').remove().sort(function(a, b) {
    var at = $(a).text(), bt = $(b).text();
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);
  }));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!